# How to reduce screenshot dimensions for putting in a macbook mockup?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-quality, mockup

I need to put a screenshot of a desktop application into a macbook mockup.
My problem is that the mockup I have needs a screenshot of 2880x1800px but my system screen is not big enough.

I have another macbook frame where I can place the screenshot but in this frame I have to reduce the size of it which makes it very blurry.

Is there anyway I can reduce the size of the screenshot or should I use some other approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the screen-template (your screenshot) will not be that big in the mockup itself.

Use the ruler to measure the size of the screen in the final mockup. if that one is smaller than the resolution of your screen, you can just scale the screenshot up to 2880x1800px what results in quality-loss. 
It will be then again resized to a smaller picture in your mockup and you wont see anymore quality-loss.

hope this helps. sry for bad english.

Answer (score -1):

If you can get a screen shot larger than the frame then there is no problem :), if you are going to reduce an image size, to keep the same quality right click on the image in the layer panel and select: "Convert to smart object" then reduce the image (Ctrl+t/Cmd+t) But hold down the shift key whilst reducing to maintain the proportions.

That should keep the same quality

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-design/smart-object-basics-in-adobe-photoshop

Comment: A Smart Object won't "keep the same quality" on output; it merely prevents you from "committing" any scaling decisions you make while working. The output still needs to be resampled down, and will suffer the same artifacting, etc.